# window Function ROW_NUMBER() changes processing ORDER BY with variable RUNNING TOTAL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I am seeing an order change when I add a column using the window function ROW_NUMBER().

The result is an incorrect running total.  (@ONorderQTYrunner)

Can anyone explain why the ROW_NUMBER() is changing the sort order and resulting in the error in running total?

The query below (with ROW_NUMBER()) is returning an unexpected RUNNINGtotal value for the 1st and 2nd rows:

```
1  57   A-123   69  4000    2020-06-10  4500
2  32   A-123   67  500     2020-07-01  500
3  59   A-123   69  2000    2020-07-15  6500
4  60   A-123   69  2000    2020-08-15  8500
```

Without ROW_NUMBER() is returning this, as I would expect:

```
57  A-123   69  4000    2020-06-10  4000
32  A-123   67  500     2020-07-01  4500
59  A-123   69  2000    2020-07-15  6500
60  A-123   69  2000    2020-08-15  8500
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PURCHASEorders` (
  `UniKey` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PARTnumber` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POnumber` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `QTY` double DEFAULT 0,
  `DOCKdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`UniKey`),
   KEY `PartNumber` (`PARTnumber`),
   KEY `POnumber` (`POnumber`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `PURCHASEorders` (`UniKey`, `PARTnumber`,`POnumber`, `QTY`, `DOCKdate`) VALUES
  ('32', 'A-123', 67, 500, '2020-07-01 12:00:00'),
  ('57', 'A-123', 69, 4000,'2020-06-10 12:00:00'),
  ('59', 'A-123', 69, 2000,'2020-07-15 12:00:00'),
  ('60', 'A-123', 69, 2000,'2020-08-15 12:00:00');
```

```
SET @PARTnumber = 'A-123';
SET @ONorderQTYrunner =0;

SELECT DISTINCT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DOCKdate ASC) AS ONorderROWindex,
    PO.UniKey,
    PO.PARTnumber,
    PO.POnumber,
    PO.QTY,
    PO.DOCKdate,
    @ONorderQTYrunner:= @ONorderQTYrunner + PO.QTY AS RUNNINGtotal
FROM PURCHASEorders PO
WHERE PO.PARTnumber = @PARTnumber 
ORDER BY PO.DOCKdate ASC
```

EDIT:
Following suggestions by Gordon Linoff using this in place of inline variable assignment has corrected the issue:

```
SUM(PO.QTY) OVER (ORDER BY PO.DOCKdate) as RUNNINGtotalfollowing
```

has corrected RUNNING total Result:

```
1  57   A-123   69  4000    2020-06-10  4000
2  32   A-123   67  500     2020-07-01  4500
3  59   A-123   69  2000    2020-07-15  6500
4  60   A-123   69  2000    2020-08-15  8500
```

Result, Root Cause of Issue: 
Variable assignment in-line which as been deprecated.
Note: This is an issue in MySql and MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable assignment in MySQL `SELECT` statements is now deprecated.  Use a proper cumulative sum:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DOCKdate ASC) AS ONorderROWindex,
       PO.UniKey, PO.PARTnumber, PO.POnumber, PO.QTY, PO.DOCKdate,
       SUM(PO.QTY) OVER (ORDER BY PO.DOCKdate) as RUNNINGtotal
FROM PURCHASEorders PO
WHERE PO.PARTnumber = @PARTnumber 
ORDER BY PO.DOCKdate ASC;
```

I doubt the `SELECT DISTINCT` is really needed, but that would be a different matter.

Comment: Using your suggestion, adding "SUM(PO.QTY) OVER (ORDER BY PO.DOCKdate) as RUNNINGtotal"  I get the correct running total, but the ONorderROWindex is not in order by DOCKdate.

Comment: @gcronin774 . . . It certainly should be.  The `ROW_NUMBER()` has an `ORDER BY` clause.  DB<>fiddle isn't working for MySQL 8, but it definitely works in MariaDB:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d2f6a4b2f36caadabd428822933754b1.

Comment: You are correct Gordon.  I misread my data vs my example.  The question has been edited to clarify solution.